# img inside nth-child of div not displaying css

Tags: image, css, css-selectors

I have a css grid where i am trying to create different behaviour on the 2nd 'box' child of the parent 'wrapper'. On inspection in Chrome, the CSS is being picked up for all the .box CSS and for the .box:nth-child(2)

And the CSS is being picked up for all the img tags with the .box img

BUT, it's not picking up the `box:nth-child(2) img`

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="height:685px">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="">
      <div>
        <img src="">
        <div class="clickableItem"><span style="font-size: 140%">Trolley Setup</span></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.wrapper:nth-child {
  width: calc( 100% / 3 );
}

.box  {
  background-color: #1786B8;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 3px 6px #4c4b4b;
  -moz-box-shadow: -3px 3px 6px #4c4b4b;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 6px #4c4b4b;
  align-self: stretch;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.box img {
  width: 120px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:20px;
}

.box a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box a div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}


.box:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  font-size:150%;
}

.box:nth-child(2) img {
  float:none;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.box:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I also tried: `.box:nth-child(2) a div img`

Comment: `:nth-child()` does just that -- selects the nth child element you specified. When you prepend a class onto it, it then becomes a filter for `:nth-child()` and only applies your rule if the nth child element has that class. In other words, it's not looking at the class first, and then selecting children from that group.

Comment: a pseudo selector applies to the element before it, so `.wrapper:nth-child(2)` will apply to any element that is a second "wrapper" class element in a parent, use `.wrapper .box:nth-child(2)` instead

Comment: Thanks @j08691 for the explanation. I understand what I've done wrong now.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I can't seem to figure out how I can instead set a rule for any img element within the 2nd child of .wrapper matching .box class.

Answer (score 0):

This rule...

```
.box a div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

...makes ALL your `img` elements flex children (since they are the direct children of the elements addresssed with that rule), so the `float` setting doesn't affect any of them. That's why there is no difference between the image inside the second child and the others.

Comment: understood, thanks. I couldn't see this was a conflict, because my rule for `.box:nth-child(2) img` wasn't being applied, so I couldn't see the CSS conflict on the chrome dev view.